# JS blocking <select> tag

Tags: javascript

Since I'm new to JavaScript, I should work on a small Calculator.

I managed to get the easy things like plus and minus,.. done, now I was trying to get myself some thoughts about getting a squareroot into it.

It is like, I have got 3 drop down - select lists. The first one is for the first number, the second one is for the symbol of the calculation, and the third one is for the second number.

But if I want to get the squareroot into it, I only need one of the select lists, so I'd like to know, if there is a way to block one of the select lists in a JS function, since I only need to block it for the sqrt?

(I'm sorry if that isn't the best english =))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your part of the logic then use the following to enable/disable...

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled = true;

document.getElementById("mySelect").disabled = false;
```

I think that's what you meant???

Comment: Great... if it's the correct answer, please mark as so